# Looking for (free) WMS of surface waters of Europe

Tags: wms, data

Do you know any WMS with hydrographic map of Europe?
Especially I am looking for map with surface waters of Europe

Comment: for free or at cost?

Comment: The best will be for free.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure one exists, however I have not found one yet.  Alternatively, you could create your own WMS using data from the [Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) site.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this site is useful for you?

http://ccm.jrc.ec.europa.eu/php/index.php?action=view&id=24